# Zoom in Corrplot for a large number of columns

Tags: r, plot, zooming, correlation

I did a correlation plot from 86 columns, but when I try to plot with the `corrplot()` I see a small figure and I cannot observe correctly the correlation from the columns. I tried to use functions like `zm()` from the **zoom** package or the `zoomplot.zoom()` and I still cannot see the plot.

This is what I get:

[image: corrplot]

Here is my code:

```
library(zoom) 
library(corrplot)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- read.csv(file = 'priorizacion_andres.csv',sep = ';')
df<-na.omit(df)

df$ï..Titulo<-NULL
M <-cor(df)
corrplot(M)
zm()
```

Comment: First maybe shrink your variable names using `tl.cex=0.5`?

Comment: Yes shortening the var names would help. Also instead of displaying the corrplot in your R session, try saving it to a file with large dimensions. For example `png('bigplot.png', height = 40, width = 40, units = 'cm'); corrplot(M, tl.cex = 0.5); dev.off()`

Comment: Thank you Quinten and qdread! I also add to your answer: `png(... ,res=360)`. If I input the width and large in cm I have to use the *res* parameter.